# Compile is successful, but no executable generated?

Tags: ros, compilation, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have created my own package in which I do some image processing with openCV and PCL. After compiling, I get no errors and the build is successful, However, no executable is generated in the /bin folder. Note: this is not my first package, I have created other nodes with no problem.

In the Cmakelist.txt, I have added the following lines

```
rosbuild_add_executable(myNode src/myNode.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(myNode src/myNode.cpp)
```

Here is the output of the compilation:

```
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 31 packages with 0 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/samme/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130322-160141
```

When I run the command `$rosun firefly_mv myNode` I get:`[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named myNode below /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/firefly_mv`.

I am not sure why the executable is not being generated here, I have created many other nodes and never got this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58901/compile-is-successful,-but-no-executable-generated?/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-03-22**:
Strange. Can you post the result of going into your "build" directory and there running "cmake ..;VERBOSE=1 make" - should show what it's doing while compiling. Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are declaring a library with the same name as the executable AFTER the executable. My guess is that only the last one is generated.

You should not build the library, try commenting that out.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4